# Passing array of arguments in command line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I had look this question about [Passing command line arguments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653563/passing-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp).

But in my case I have to pass array of parameters to the calling .exe file.

e.g.

```
var arr = new string[] {"Item title","New task","22","High Priority"}
```

Is it possible to use `Process.Start()` with exe path along with the array

I have the .exe path

```
const string path = @"C:\Projects\Test\test.exe";
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape command line arguments in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510343/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Most answers in this question are wrong, bad, incomplete or just more or less unsafe when the arguments contain special characters like quotes or whitespaces. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040946)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
        var arr = new string[] {"Item title", "New task", "22", "High Priority"};
        const string path = @"C:\Projects\Test\test.exe";
        const string argsSeparator = " ";
        string args = string.Join(argsSeparator, arr);

        Process.Start(path, args);
```

Comment: And how will he know if space is part of argument or separator? :D

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura then maybe 

`string args = string.Join(" ", arr.Select(e => "\"" + e + "\""));` ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura If separator is not space he may use any other separator :) just change a const. Thanks for comment.

Comment: If done "correctly" and working for _arbitrary_ arguments, it is a little more [complicated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/17/10063629.aspx). Basically, you have to apply the rules of [CommandLineToArgv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) but in reverse. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611075/21567).

Comment: This answer is so wrong.. stringizing process arguments in Windows is much more complicated. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040946)

Comment: DON'T EVER do this. Otherwise we'd never get rid of all those sh*tty applications which can not even start from a directory with spaces in path.

Answer (score -3):

One option is to put the array in one string so it is viewed as one argument by the method. In your method, you can then parse that one argument. Something like:

```
"Item title, New task, 22, High Priority"
```

You can use your existing array by doing:

```
var arrAsOneString = string.Join(", ", arr);
```

Inside your method, do:

```
var values = argument.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
```

I added the trim to do away with spaces.

Answer (score -4):

Its not possible to pass array as argument, you can pass a string with Comma Separator:

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.Arguments = "Item title,New task,22,High Priority"
```